# How can I solve Error with opening Studio App in Odoo?

Tags: xpath, odoo, contacts, odoo-15

I have the following Problem, when beeing logged in as admin:

- I can access the Contacts Module and the records in it.
- When I try to open the Studio App in Contacts Modul nothing happens. It does not open.
- When I try to open a record after trying to open the Studio App I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo15-prod/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 644, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo15-prod/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 302, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Element '<xpath expr="//field[@name=&#39;id&#39;]">' cannot be located in parent view
```

So the error only appears, when I first try to open the Studio App. Other wise I can open the records! And it only happens in this specific module.

I looked up which field is mentioned in the xpath expression and its technical name is "translate". But I can`t find the xpath expression in any view from res.partner model.

Has anyone a tip how I can find the mentioned xpath ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Error loaded Odoo Studio custom views don't lead to errors for normal users (anymore), because Odoo will just ignore them in this case. But opening studio itself on models views customized by studio, will always try to load those error loaded views. Unfortunately studio doesn't show any errors to the studio user.

What can you do? If you don't know the error, search for every studio view on the related model and archive them or try to look into them to find the error. You could also try the trial-and-error approach by commenting things out from the end of the view arch one after the other.

If you know the error, you have the possibility to search for views having the element named in the error message. But don't forget to replace HTML codes with real characters. Your example should be replaced by:

```xml
expr="//field[@name='id']"
```

Just search on the `arch` field in the search bar of the views. It's the last field and is labeled "View Architecture". In the end fix the error.

Comment: Thank you. I only had one studio view, deactivating it worked.